# VBA SUMIFS using last row and date ranges from multiple worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have three worksheets in use for this code - payment entry, transactions, and final bill. I want to sum column B in transactions, while searching the date column (column D) if it is between the date range requested on the payment entry sheet, and if the name matches column B on the final bill. The sum that fits these constraints will be printed to the E column on the final bill sheet.

This is the correct Excel syntax for one of the rows

`=SUMIFS(Transactions!B3:B53, Transactions!D3:D53, ">="&'Payment Entry'!L20:M20, Transactions!D3:D53, "<="&'Payment Entry'!O20:P20, Transactions!A3:A53, 'Final Bill'!B6)`

Now, I want to search the transactions page for the last row (instead of row 50) in the above code for each of the populated rows for column E (so instead of B6, it searches for the current row from the B column) on the final bill page.

This is my approach but I get a syntax error:

```
Dim final As Worksheet
Dim database As Worksheet
Dim payment As Worksheet
Dim CLastFundRow As Integer

Set final = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Final Bill")
Set database = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Transactions")
Set payment = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Payment Entry")

CLastFundRow = database.Range("A3").End(xlDown).Row

final.Range("E6:E100").FormulaR1C1 =SUMIFS(database.range("B3:B" & CLastFundRow & ", database.Range("D3:D" & CLastFundRow & "), ">="& payment.Range("L20:M20"), database.Range("D3:D" & CLastFundRow & "), "<="&'payment.Range("O20:P20"), database("A3:A5" & CLastFundRow & "), final.range("B6")
```

Edit to add solution:

````
CLastFinRow = final.Range("B6").End(xlDown).Row

final.Range("E6:E" & CLastFinRow).Formula2 = "=SUMIFS(Transactions!B$3:B$" & CLastFundRow & ", Transactions!D$3:D$" & CLastFundRow & ","">=""&'Payment Entry'!$L$20:$M$20, Transactions!D$3:D$" & CLastFundRow & ", ""<=""&'Payment Entry'!$O$20:$P$20, Transactions!A$3:A$" & CLastFundRow & ", 'Final Bill'!B6)"```
````

Answer (score -1):

You are setting the formula for the cell as text, so you cant use the ranges the way tou were using the hence the sintax error

```
final.Range("E6:E100").Formula ="SUMIFS("Transacion!B3:B" & CLastFundRow & ", Transactions!D3:D" & CLastFundRow & ",>='Payment Entry'!L20:M20, Transactions!D3:D" & CLastFundRow & ", <='Payment Entry'!O20:P20, transactions!A3:A5" & CLastFundRow & ", 'Final Bill'!B6")
```

Comment: vba formula must be in quotes ie `Range.Formula = "=SUM(A1)"` your concatenation is off and will not compile: `final.Range("E6:E100").Formula = "=SUMIFS(Transacion!B3:B" & CLastFundRow & ", Transactions!D3:D" & CLastFundRow & ",>='Payment Entry'!L20:M20, Transactions!D3:D" & CLastFundRow & ", <='Payment Entry'!O20:P20, transactions!A3:A5" & CLastFundRow & ", 'Final Bill'!B6)"`

Comment: @ScottCraner I am getting an application- defined or object-defined error now. Is the syntax for the last row portion and the syntax for the >= and <= correct? Also do you know how to automate the current row number within the B column for the B6 portion?

Comment: sorry @LearningandImproving: `final.Range("E6:E100").Formula = "=SUMIFS(Transacion!B3:B" & CLastFundRow & ", Transactions!D3:D" & CLastFundRow & ","">=""&'Payment Entry'!L20:M20, Transactions!D3:D" & CLastFundRow & ", ""<=""&'Payment Entry'!O20:P20, transactions!A3:A5" & CLastFundRow & ", 'Final Bill'!B6)"`

Comment: @ScottCraner It's adding an @ sign in front of 'Payment Entry' in the cells which makes all the cells sum to 0. Also instead of changing just the last cell number for B6, it changes all the ranges so the first cell's formula is ```=SUMIFS(Transactions!B3:B53, Transactions!D3:D53,">="&@'Payment Entry'!L20:M20, Transactions!D3:D53, "<="&@'Payment Entry'!O20:P20, Transactions!A3:A53, 'Final Bill'!B6)``` and the second is ```=SUMIFS(Transactions!B4:B54, Transactions!D4:D54,">="&@'Payment Entry'!L21:M21, Transactions!D4:D54, "<="&@'Payment Entry'!O21:P21, Transactions!A4:A54, 'Final Bill'!B7)```

Comment: Use formula2 then.

Comment: @ScottCraner I think I may have been unclear, it does changes the ranges for each cell within the column, where I only want the last part to be changed according to its row (B6, B7, B8,...) and not the transactions!B4:B54, Payment Entry!L21:M21 portions. I also don't know how VBA added the @ sign to the formula because then it makes the formula not work.

Comment: @ScottCraner I solved the @ sign appearing - there must be a 2 added to the end of the .Formula so it's ```.Formula2". Now this code works for the first cell B6, perfectly! The ranges on the following cells are the only part not working now